# Run mongoimport in a complete isolation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

We planning our data migration from one standalone server to other standalone server. (we can't use replication due to some constraint)

We had used `fsyncLock()` and `fsyncUnlock()` to ensure complete isolation during **`mongodump`**

but we are are unsure how to run **`mongoimport`** on complete isolation.

Trying to think what could be the best way we can achieve this nothing concrete.

- Like stopping all our services and then mongoimport.

Does mongodb provide anything here? how does one gaurantee consistency with mongoimport.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB Atlas then you can try [Migrate Deployments](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/cloud-manager/migration/) might reduce the downtime to a minimum. There are workflows for live migration.

In the background, mitigation runs [mongomirror](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/mongomirror/) for easy migration.